# Extract common class behaviour in a template

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I observed that in my program I needed to make several classes use the following common pattern. The idea behind it is that `resource_mgr` maintains a list of reference-counted pointers to `resource` objects, and exclusively controls their lifetime. Clients may not create or delete `resource` instances, but may request them from `resource_mgr`.

```
class resource_impl
{
    public:
        // ...

    private:
        resource_impl(...);
        ~resource_impl();
        // ...
        friend class resource_mgr;
}

class resource_mgr
{
    public:
        // ...
        shared_ptr<resource_impl> new_resource(...);

    private:
        std::vector<shared_ptr<resource_impl> > resources_;
        static void delete_resource(resource* p); // for shared_ptr
}
```

How can I (or can I?) define a template to capture this common behavior?
The following illustrates how this template might be used:

```
class texture_data
{
    // texture-specific stuff
}

typedef resource_impl<texture_data> texture_impl;
// this makes texture_impl have private *tors and friend resource_mgr<texture_impl>

typedef resource_mgr<texture_impl> texture_mgr;

//...

texture_mgr tmgr;
shared_ptr<texture_impl> texture = tmgr.new_resource(...);
```

**Update:** Various instantiations of `resource_impl` should all have in common the following properties:

- They have private constructors and destructor
- Their "associated" `resource_mgr` (the manager class that manages the same type of resource) is a friend class (so it can create/destroy instances)

Comment: What common behaviour? Of resource_imp?

Comment: Of both `resource_impl` and `resource_mgr`.

Comment: And how is `resource` coming into play there?

Comment: `resource` is just a typedef that I use. I will remove it from the question to make things more clear.

Comment: Can you show example or psudocode of a couple of objects that would use this shared functionality, and psudocode that illustrates how you'd like to use it?

Comment: How about making `resource_mgr` a template?

Comment: Requiring the resource to know about the thing managing it ... seems ugly.  Is it really necessary to *prohibit* people from instantiating your resources directly, can't you just stop them actually doing it?

Comment: @Useless What do you mean? How can I stop clients from doing it without prohibiting instantiation?

Comment: Walk over (or send them a message) and say "don't do that, do this". Unless the resource management is genuinely an intrinsic part of the resource itself, of course.

Comment: I am trying to apply guidelines that I read about, in this case having the compiler alert me if this requirement (of non-instantiation) is broken.

Comment: Fair enough - the manager still doesn't exclusively control lifetime btw: you're giving out shared_ptrs, and they can keep your resources alive whatever the manager does.

Comment: That's the correct behaviour - perhaps my wording is wrong. The manager is allowed to destroy a resource only when it's the sole owner (i.e. no clients require the resource). I guess that's not lifetime control, but construction and destruction control.

Comment: `resource_impl<texture_data>` and other `resource_impl` instantiation - do they have same methods? How do they look like?

Comment: No, they do not have the same methods. They share the fact that they have private *tors and they friend their respective `resource_mgr`, but other than that they have different methods and members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add the interface :

```
class resource_interface
{
  public:
    virtual ~resource_interface() = 0;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Then change the resource_impl into template :

```
template< typename T >
class resource_impl : public T
{
    public:
        // ...

    private:
        resource_impl(...);
        ~resource_impl();
        // ...
        friend template< typename > class resource_mgr;
}
```

Then change resource_mgr into template:

```
template< typename T >
class resource_mgr
{
    public:
        // ...
        shared_ptr<T> new_resource(...);

    private:
        std::vector<shared_ptr<T> > resources_;
        static void delete_resource(T* p); // for shared_ptr
}
```

And you should have very generic resource_impl and resource_mgr classes.

Comment: Can I force at compile-time that, for template `resource_mgr`, typename T be a `resource_impl` template (i.e. disallow `resource_mgr<int>`)?